# Custom Search JSON API с использованием оператора site

Tags: php, google-search

Мне нужно проверять несколько сот сайтов/страниц в день на наличие гугл индекса, по сути нужна имитация site:something.com. Использую Custom Search JSON AP

```
$search_query = http_build_query(
      array(
          "key" => $api_key, 
          "cx" => $search_id,
          "q" => "site:".$link,
          "num" => "10",
          "safe" => "off"
      )
  );

  $json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?" . $search_query);
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
```

и зачастую в ответе показывает, что нет результатов, хотя сайт в индексе есть. Проверял "ручками" через сам гугл.

В чём может быть проблема/ошибка?

Comment: Очень подозреваю что в ```file_get_contents``` а точнее в заголовках которые он передает, если опишите точнее что именно "не так" в моменты когда нет результатов(коды ответов например) - можно будет не гадать а сказать точнее

Comment: если через скрипт отправить запрос "q" => "site:mysite.com", то в ответе (переменная а ответе items) результатов нет, но если site:mysite.com ввести в поисковую строку, то сайт находит. Конкретно что за сайт не могу сказать - модеры его из сообщения потрут

Comment: так же тестировал чере https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22cx%22%3A%22df93080fceb189de3%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fonodo.org%2Fvisualizations%2F208836%22%2C%22safe%22%3A%22off%22%7D

Comment: у меня такое чувство,что у сайта гугла и API разные базы индекса